# App Release Version crashes Debug Version works, no idea why

Tags: iphone, ios

So I have this app I'm working on and after building running the App from XCode on the device everything works fine. However after installing the same App from the App Store (no changes only the provisioning profile is different) the App crashes shortly before it starts.

Console errors:

```
Fri Sep 30 12:48:42 unknown locationd[540] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [locationd] (550.32)
Fri Sep 30 12:49:47 itess Ola Portugal[556] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: com.mindovertech.olaportugal [Ola Portugal] (550.32)


Fri Sep 30 12:49:47 itess kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[556] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)


Fri Sep 30 12:49:47 itess kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[556] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/13E9B45C-84ED-4FD3-BDAA-8527BA34CB3F [69] (sandbox)


Fri Sep 30 12:49:47 itess Ola Portugal[556] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib


Fri Sep 30 12:49:47 itess Ola Portugal[556] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/PDFPatch_CVE-2010-1797.dylib


Fri Sep 30 12:49:49 itess locationd[557] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [locationd] (550.32)


Fri Sep 30 12:49:51 itess Ola Portugal[556] <Warning>: Warning: Libinfo call to mDNSResponder on main thread


Fri Sep 30 12:49:56 itess ReportCrash[559] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process Ola Portugal[556]


Fri Sep 30 12:49:57 itess com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.mindovertech.olaportugal[0xeace][556]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.mindovertech.olaportugal[0xeace]) Job appears to have crashed: Bus error


Fri Sep 30 12:49:57 itess SpringBoard[28] <Warning>: Application 'Olá Portugal' exited abnormally with signal 10: Bus error


Fri Sep 30 12:49:57 itess ReportCrash[559] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/Ola Portugal_2011-09-30-124953_itess.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Device log:

```
Incident Identifier: B2ABCA98-7942-4FF2-968A-F5FE4AFDDE4D
CrashReporter Key:   fd9745556d91de13e834ad1bbd0bee6c29b17976
Hardware Model:      iPod2,1
Process:         Ola Portugal [556]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/13E9B45C-84ED-4FD3-BDAA-8527BA34CB3F/Ola Portugal.app/Ola Portugal
Identifier:      Ola Portugal
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-09-30 12:49:53.028 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.0 (8A293)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00816a00
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                             0x00816a00 0 + 8481280
```

(Didn t copy the other threads because they seems to be fine)

Here's one more detail, the device where it crashes is an iPod touch running 4.0 
The same App (from the App Store) works perfectly on an iPhone4/iPad2 running 4.3.3 
I'm not sure if the problem is with the device or with the OS and what I can do to fix it.

Like I said before If I run the debug version on the device from XCode it works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: May be an issue with the optimization level...Check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this kind of error occurs when we are updating new version on store because of coredata.

If you have changed any thing related to coredata then you need to delete old .Sqlite file at first launch of new version. remember not every time to delete .squlite but only once the application starts and old file exist.

Comment: Greetings, I forgot about this thread. I eventually found out it had to do with iAD, I was using an instruction available on 4.1 but not 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about this thread. I eventually found out it had to do with iAD, I was using an instruction available on 4.1 but not 4.0